# Default Binding changed for checkbox after upgrade to VS2013 and .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, visual-studio-2013

After upgrading a project written in VS2012 against .NET 4.5 to VS2013 .NET 4.5.1 I the binding to my checkboxes throw an invalidoperation exception: *A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property*

```
<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" Content="Invert TXD" IsChecked="{Binding EepromDataModel.InvertTxd}"/>
```

After adding the correct mode (OneWay) it runs fine.

Is the default bindingmode changed or is it stricter then before?

Don't get me wrong. I should have added that bindingmode before, but I was just wondering...

**Edit**

The Property wasn't changed. It had always a private setter. I only did the upgrade, nothing more.
I have just quadruple-checked again with the code for VS2012 and there it runs fine without any exceptions thrown.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Are you sure you didn't change the field on your view model to private set?

Comment: It did had a private setter before.

Comment: Seems to me like a bug fix, although it might have broken your code. a CheckBox is an editable UI element  (like a TextBox) as opposed to a read-only UI element (like a TextBLOCK) which is not editable by the end user and two-way binding is what makes most sense as a default option.

Comment: It does indeed make more sense. Like I said, I should have added the OneWay bindingmode before (must have overlooked that), but I was just wondering if something had changed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, especially with DevExpress WPF controls

Comment: @lvmeijer Changing your bindingmode to OneWay or makeing your setter public should solve your issue. Like I stated in my question: I (and therefore you too ;-) ) should have set the binding mode in the first place and then we would have never encountered this issue. Hopefully it didn't break to much at your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a security bug in the .net framework which was introduced in 4.5. Private setters should not handle the databinding of a TwoWay binding. In the following issue microsoft commented on the issue:

[Connect bug two way databinding on private methods](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773682/wpf-property-with-private-setter-i)

[Security update for two way binding on private methods](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840642)

Comment: Thanks peer. Seems that @HighCore was right in his comment. Thanks for the follow up. An old question rarely gets an answer. +1 for that.

Comment: We were wondering about the behavior and found your question and the cause. Connecting then for future reference.